# How to get Id of an element without getElementById

Tags: javascript

lets say we got this html scenario:

Please note:

The forms "action" and "method" attributes are omitted on purpose. The "form" tag is just here because in my real project, I have a similar scenario and having the form around all those fields may help in handling the request.

```
<form id="form1">
    <div id="wrapperDiv">
        <div id="div1">
            <input type="text" id="searchField"/>
        </div>
        <div id="div2">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="callFunction(this);">Hello</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function callFunction(x)
    {
         //When invoked this function sets the value of "searchField" to the respective link tag innerHTML
         //to set this you cant use something like:
         // var y = document.getElementById("searchField");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Is your markup structure likely to change? Are you open to using jQuery?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid using `getElementById`? Please describe your limitations so that we'll be able to give you a proper answer.

Comment: @techfoobar yes jQuery libraries can be added.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov I am making a jsf ui:component. The id's are created trough elvariables and this component should be reusable so I cannot relay on getElmenentById.

Comment: Will there always be a 1:1 relationship between the `a` and the `input` elements (the first `input` value will have the text of the first `a`, the second `input` will have the value of the second `a`)?

Answer (score 3):

To get the value of the text input element, we can use the value property of the text input object: `text_val = oText.value;`

As an example, if we have the following text input element:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="txt_name" size="30" maxlength="70">
```

We can access the value of the element like this:

```
name = oForm.elements["name"].value;
```

To obtain a reference to a text input element, here is some sample code:

`oText = oForm.elements["text_element_name"];` OR

```
oText = oForm.elements[index];
```

In the code above, “index” is the position of the element in the 0-based elements array, and oForm is the form object reference obtained using the document.forms collection:

```
oForm = document.forms[index];
```

Comment: Yes but there You are using callFunction(x) which gets an argument of the form, indeed it's one of the way to access the form.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that there is only one input element in your div:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('div1');
var element = parent.GetElementsByTagName('input')[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but please note I cannot use any getElementById declaration. That are my limitations.

Comment: You can try this jquery var element = $('#div1 input');

Answer (score 1):

You can make it easy if using jQuery. You can use:

```
function callFunction(x) {
    var y = $(this).closest('form').find('input[type="text"]:first');
    y.val(this.innerHTML);
}
```

to get the search field.

Answer (score 0):

you can use     var y= document.getElementsByTagName("input");

Comment: What if there is more than one input?

Comment: var     y=document.getElementsByTagName("*")     //returns all elements on page

Comment: How is getting all elements useful?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is the following:

```
function findIndex(el, container) {
    // we can't do anything without a node to work on
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        // container must be a node, if no container is supplied the body is used
        container = container || document.body;
        // finds all elements of the same tagName as the node
        // (el) passed to the function that are within the container node
        var els = container.getElementsByTagName(el.tagName);
        // iterates through each of these nodes
        for (var i = 0, len = els.length; i < len; i++) {
            // sets the 'data-index' attribute to be equal to 'i'
            els[i].setAttribute('data-index', i);
        }
        // returns the generated index from the 'el' node passed into the function
        return el.getAttribute('data-index');
    }
}

function callFunction(el) {
    // if no el passed in, we stop here
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        // sets the 'i' variable equal to the value of the 'data-index' attribute
        // if it exists, if it doesn't then we generate it
        var i = el.dataIndex ? el.getAttribute('data-index') : findIndex(el, document.forms.form1);
        // if an index is found (the 'i' variable) we set the value of
        // the 'input' with that index to be equal to the text contained
        // within the clicked link
        if (i) {
            document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].value = (el.textContent || el.innerText);
        }
        // if no index is returned then we exit here
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        callFunction(this);
    }
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yTLjM/2/).

This does assume that there exists a direct relationship between the *n*<sup>th</sup> `input` and the *n*<sup>th</sup> `a` elements.

I've also moved away from using in-line event-handlers, in order to make maintenance a little easier (and the JavaScript less obtrusive). The first call to the `callFunction()` gives all the `a` elements (and a parent/ancestor can be specified to restrict the indexing to only those `a` elements within a given ancestor node/element), and subsequent calls use the generated `data-index` attribute (rather than re-generating indices).

References:

- [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getAttribute).
- [`Element.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName).
- [`Element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute).